# Returning/Stopping the execution of a function on a keypress in Java

Tags: java, return, control-flow, program-flow

I have a certain function in my program that I want to stop on the press of a key. I have a native keyboard hook set up for that purpose. Right now, I call System.exit(0) when that key is detected. However, I don't want to exit the program, just stop that operation and return to where it was called. An example is given below.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Calling function that can be stopped with CTRL+C");
        foo(); // Should return when CTRL+C is pressed
        System.out.println("Function has returned");
    }
}
```

I've tried putting the call to foo() in a thread so I could call `Thread.interrupt()` but I want the function call to be blocking, not non-blocking. Also there are blocking IO calls in `foo()` so I'd rather not deal with interrupts unless it's necessary, because I'd have to deal with `ClosedByInterruptException` exceptions and that has caused problems before.

Also the body of `foo()` is very long and has many function calls inside it, so writing `if (stop == true) return;` in the function is not an option.

Is there a better way to do this than making a blocking thread? If so, how? If not, how would I make a blocking thread?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Is it the case that you want `foo()` to return immediately, no matter what it is doing at the time, when a key is pressed?  You say `foo` does blocking I/O calls... if `foo` is in a blocking call when the key is pressed, do you want it immediately interrupted?

Comment: No I do want it to be immediately interrupted. When I mentioned that, I was thinking off how I would have to catch another exception (`ClosedByInterruptException`), and how when I tried that it screwed a lot of things up. But I definitely want it to stop no matter what it's doing. I clarified that in the post.

Comment: In English, it's either "No I ***do not*** want..." or "Yes I ***do*** want...". Your reply is still ambiguous, can you please clarify.

Comment: I apologize. Yes, I do want execution to be immediately interrupted, no matter what.

Comment: This is very hard to get right, and you may not be able to cover all cases when `foo` is blocked on I/O.  Essentially, you must run `foo` on its own thread and the keyboard monitor on another, and then interrupt `foo` at the appropriate moment. Then `foo` has to check a flag set by the keyboard monitor at appropriate places and return.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
// Create and start the thread
MyThread thread = new MyThread();
thread.start();

while (true) {
    // Do work

    // Pause the thread
    synchronized (thread) {
        thread.pleaseWait = true;
    }

    // Do work

    // Resume the thread
    synchronized (thread) {
        thread.pleaseWait = false;
        thread.notify();
    }

    // Do work
}

class MyThread extends Thread {
    boolean pleaseWait = false;

    // This method is called when the thread runs
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            // Do work

            // Check if should wait
            synchronized (this) {
                while (pleaseWait) {
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            }

            // Do work
        }
    }
}
```

(taken from http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/PauseThread.html not my own work)